# Переменная в виде свойства js

Tags: javascript

Появилась необходимость менять некоторые типы свойства style

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var type = top;
elem.style.type = 100+'px';
```

Не могу понять, как подобное реализовать что-бы работало

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var type = 'top';
elem.style[type] = 100 + 'px';
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помог)

Answer (score 7):

Вот так.
Подробнее про [квадратные скобки](https://learn.javascript.ru/object#kvadratnye-skobki)

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.element')
let type = 'top';
element.style[type] = `${100}px`
type = 'left'
element.style[type] = `${100}px`
```

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)